# powers of derivatives notation with Leibniz

Tags: derivatives, notation

Lets say I have a function $ y=f(x)\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=f'(x) $
If I want to do a power of the derivative,namely $(f'(x)^3) $ how would I write it in Leibniz notation? $(\frac{dy}{dx})^3=\frac{d^3y^3}{d^3x^3}$? find it a bit confusing.

Would appreciate any reference, all Google brings me to is derivatives of power functions.

Comment: Definitely $(dy/dx)^3$.

Comment: which can be expanded to $ \frac{(dy)^3}{(dx)^3} $ and that's it?

Comment: No. $dy/dx$ is not an actual fraction. You would have to leave it like $(dy/dx)^3$.

Comment: @GReyes, I think you could post your comments as an answer so this no longer appears unanswered

Answer (score 4):

Suppose a dependent parameter $y$ represents a function $f$ of an independent parameter $x$, that is, $y=f(x)$.

Then the derivative of the function $f$, in Leibniz's notation [1] for differentiation, can be written [2] as:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} \quad or \quad \frac{d(f(x))}{dx}
$$

If $y = f(x)$, the $nth$ derivative of $f$ in Leibniz notation is given by:
$$
f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{d^{n}y}{dx^{n}}
$$

And therefore for your case we will have:
$$
f^{(3)}(x)=\frac{d^{3}y}{dx^{3}}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\right)
$$

Sincerely I hope this will help you.

Good luck!

1. William L. Briggs, "Calculus for scientists and engineers : early transcendentals.", year 2013, pages 131-132.
2. Joseph Mazur, "Enlightening Symbols. A Short History of Mathematical Notation and Its Hidden Powers.", year 2014, pages 221-222.